# tn5250 won't install, needs libssl0.9.6 but libssl0.9.8 is installed

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install a 5250 emulator so I downloaded the debian version of tn5250 from source forge, when I try to install it I was missing libssl0.9.6 so I went to get it and libssl0.9.8 came up instead so I installed that but tn5250 is still wanting libssl0.9.6.
I tried rebooting and retrying tn5250, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get remove libssl0.9.8
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.6
```

Comment: Please test your commands before posting them on Ask Ubuntu; `libssl0.9.8` is in the repos, but `libssl0.9.6` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from here:

http://archive.debian.net/es/woody/i386/libssl0.9.6/download

"Please note that this site contains information about obsolete Debian releases"

I use it and it works.